# Check FME license with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am wondering if there is possible to check If there is a free FME license with python. I will my python code run the FME workbench, but first check if one is available.  This is how I will avoid some issues with python later.

Answer (score 1):

You clould execute lmutil.exe from python. Use the subprocess module. The article http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Check-who-is-using-FME-floating-licenses
describes how to query the status of a license server with lmutil.exe.